# How to detect OutOfMemoryError via JMX

Tags: java, out-of-memory, heap-memory, jmx

Which MBean tells me that a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space has happened to my Java application that i supervise via JMX.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Agreed there is no bean but you can monitor your heap size via jmx.

As pap mentioned the JVM is left in an indeterminable state, I am not really sure why the java engineers did this as it can mask the fact that you have had an OOM. In most instances I find it best to get the heap and kill the JVM which you can do with the following properties.

-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately, none.  i would love it if *something* in the jvm remembered that an OOME had been thrown, but currently (at least as of jdk 6) nothing does.

About the best you can do is set thresholds in the MemoryPools and see when those thresholds have been surpassed (although that doesn't necessarily mean you are out of memory...).

Answer (score 2):

OutOfMemoryError is sort of the last cry for help from the JVM. By the very design of it, when the JVM throws this error, it will be in an indeterminable state. Allthough the JVM *might* recover from an OOM state, it's not something that can be relied on and it's completely in-deterministic. Particularly "PermGen space" is almost guaranteed to be a dead end so you can't rely on the JVM responding to really anything, including JMX.

As was propsed by jtahlborn, you can monitor memory-pools and try to catch the error before it happens, but that probably won't be very precise. Another option is to continually check the system-err log and trap the exception as it gets logged.